# broccoli build dist - build fail

Tags: javascript, babeljs, broccolijs

I'm using broccoli with the plugins shown below:

- broccoli-babel-transpiler
- broccoli-funnel
- broccoli-concat
- broccoli-merge-trees

But after running `broccoli build dist` I get the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli-babel-transpiler\index.js\node
_modules\babel-core'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:765:18)
    at walkSync (E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\node_modules\walk-sync\index.js:14:20)
    at Funnel.processFilters (E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:113:15)
    at Funnel.rebuild (E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:108:10)
    at E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli\lib\api_compat.js:42:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:489:
16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.j
s:501:17)
    at E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1095:13
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (E:\newPojects\es6-webiste\node_modules\broccoli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1290:9)

Build failed
```

Comment: [https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-babel-and-broccoli/](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-babel-and-broccoli/) this is the example that I'm following.

Comment: Maybe try to delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again?

Comment: nope, It didn't work

Comment: Are you using the exact Brocfile.js from Mozilla Hacks? Just to know what to debug

Comment: Thanks for asking, now I'm doing this stuff with gulp

Answer (score 0):

It seems be a path error.[I tried to modify the RegExp as follow,it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HOmA.jpg)

```
babelPath = babelPath.replace(/\\index.js$/, '');
```